# PHP Time() Storage in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

With the creation of $timeStamp = time();
I want to store that in a 'timeStamp' db column.

My questions though are:

What is the set up for this in MySQL?

Would it be an int?  What would the length/values be?  Is 10 enough?

I have also read various threads about having it be unsigned, does this matter?

I am using time(); because I also want to use this as a specific gallery ID in an XML attribute so that if a user changes their gallery it would then update the 'timeStamp' field in the db, thus creating a new gallery ID each time the XML is generated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is a DATETIME type in MySql to store date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP's time() value is just an integer. Use a standard mysql `int` to store it. The "length" field is irrelevant. an int(1) and an int(234234234234234) will both occupy the exact same storage internally - 4 bytes. The `(x)` number is purely for DISPLAY purposes. `int(1)` would only show one digit when you select the value, even though the number stored internally has however many digits it has.

Comment: Thanks Marc! I think it defaulted to (10) when I set it up, will that be fine to leave that or should I remove it.  Also, I will need the full input since I will be comparing it each time.

Comment: If you try to insert a value larger than the defined size, what happens?  I think there are constraints applied by the data size defined. Can't test it at the moment.  The internal storage size may be the same, but I think there might be more to it.  Try using an int(1) I think it will truncate or round your timestamp

Comment: If there is such a constraint then using unsigned ints will allow you to go twice as high in value.  So then it becomes a question of how far into the future these date values might ever be.

Comment: Thanks Evan.  So (10) is enough as long as its 'unsigned'?  These dates will go to infinity and beyond!  Probably not, but yeah I guess I could just put it at (20) and be safe?

Comment: @user3417476 The 10 in INT(10) has got nothing to do with the range of valid values. That's Marcs main message, but Marc is at fault by saying it would only show one digit. If you store 15 in an INT(1) column, it will be displayed as 15. Please have a look at the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/numeric-type-attributes.html): *The display width does not constrain the range of values that can be stored in the column. Nor does it prevent values wider than the column display width from being displayed correctly.*

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't matter.

But if you want to have auto updating column, you need to use TIMESTAMP.

**UNSIGNED INT:** You need to handle timezone conversions, can't auto update.

**TIMESTAMP:** Converts your timestamp to GMT timezone to store it internally, when selecting it will be converted to current php timezone.

**DATETIME:** You need to handle timezone conversions, can't auto update (you can after 5.6.5).

Comment: Thanks newboyhun.  Yeah I was reading about TIMESTAMP however, I was thinking things might get wonky when creating the XML file and there being a space in the format (from what I have read so far).  Going with an int value using time(); seemed more friendly... not sure if that makes sense.

Comment: Since MySQL 5.6.5 there's [automatic initialization and/or update](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/timestamp-initialization.html) for DATETIME too - and it's not limited to one column anymore.

Comment: @VMai Ahh yes totally forgot about that, edited, thanks.

user3417476: Space in the format? You can always edit your own string. INT is not friendly, because you need to do everything, but if you don't have to deal with timezone it's OK.

Comment: I would prefer a MySQL TIMESTAMP or DATETIME column (with automatic initialization) myself, but using an ordinary auto_increment INT column for the gallery ID.

Comment: Newboyhun, yeah I am not ever displaying or converting the value.  Just using it as unique ID every time an update is made.  In regards to the space, when I tried some other tests I was getting YYYY:MM:DD SS: etc... and was getting a space in between the date and time.  I figured since I am never actually displaying this using just an 'int' from time(); would suffice.

Comment: @VMai, well there is an auto_increment INT column for a gallery ID, however if a change has been made to an asset or the gallery, that column INT would remain the same and thus the playback component would never know every time it checks in.  I figured setting a stamp of some type upon creation and update would be a good way to create a unique ID each time.  Thus, on check in with playback component it can compare and then regrab the new XML.

Comment: @user3417476 You know your use case best. I've seen too many attempts with datetime conversations of "convenient" unix timestamps :-) But I would rather let MySQL handle this with an automatic update column (datetime or timestamp dependent on the MySQL version) as doing it myself. The display could be done with UNIX_TIMESTAMP(https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp) if an integer would be more convenient than a DATETIME string representation (assuming this check should be done without the need of a database query).